# How to deploy our app which is running on parcel bundler

Tags: node.js, npm, parceljs, npm-run

In my recent project, I have made an animated website using gsap and parcel-bundler. When I want to run it, I will type `parcel index.html` or `npm run dev` and it will start a server on port 1234, making it accessible at http://localhost:1234/.

Can anyone tell me how to deploy it to netlify or Heroku?

My package.json file looks like this

```
{
   "name":"expportfolio",
   "version":"1.0.0",
   "description":"",
   "main":"app.js",
   "scripts":{
      "dev":"parcel index.html",
      "build":"parcel build index.html"
   },
   "author":"",
   "license":"ISC",
   "devDependencies":{
      "cssnano":"^4.1.10",
      "sass":"^1.26.7"
   },
   "dependencies":{
      "@dogstudio/highway":"^2.2.1",
      "gsap":"^3.3.0"
   }
}
```

Terminal:
[image: Terminal Screenshot]

Web:
[image: Web Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

There must be a command in parcel that will build your project. You can upload your project to netlify and then add this command to its `Build Settings` console and it'll use that command to build your application. You can define a lot of other stuff there too.

If this project is on github, you can just add your github account to netlify and directly transfer it over there.

ref: https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/get-started/#basic-build-settings

Answer (score 0):

just use this command on the terminal on your project file: npx parcel build src/index.html. where src is the folder where index.html is and you will get a build on dist folder. Directly deploy it on netlify or any other platform easily.

Answer (score -1):

Try this command from the docs: parcel build index.html